# Rails - Invoicing App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Invoicing App in Rails, which has the following models.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :items

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :items, through: :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  after_initialize :set_total

  def set_total 
    total = 0 
    items.to_a.each do |item| 
      total += item.price * item.qty 
    end 
    self.total = total 
  end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :invoices, through: :line_items

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :item
```

At the moment I am able to successfully generate the invoices. The issue is the invoice's total amount changes whenever I change an item's price that is referenced to the generated invoice.

What would be the best way to prevent that from happening ? As soon as the  invoice is created, I don't want any changes applied to its total.

Thanks

Comment: Are you storing the `total` in the `invoice` table? Can you provide the implementation details of the `set_total` method.

Comment: @Dharam The total attribute is stored in the invoice table,, here is the method                                  `def set_total
    total = 0
    items.to_a.each do |item|
      total += item.price * item.qty
    end
    self.total = total
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new_record? method,

```js
  after_initialize :set_total

  def set_total 
    total = 0 
    items.to_a.each do |item| 
      total += item.price * item.qty 
    end 
    self.total = total if self.new_record?
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`after_initialize` is invoked, both while initializing a new record as well as while fetching the record from the database.

You may want to use `before_create` in place of `after_initialize` so that the total is set only once before_creating and is not updated every time when the record is initialized.

You could also simplify the `set_total` method as follows:

```
def set_total
  self.total = items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + (item.price * item.qty) }
end
```

Refer to [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for more info about inject.

Comment: Hi @Dharam, I did try this way and for some reason, the total is saved as 0 right now,,,